# Why don't glColor3f() and glTranslated() affect object creation?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glfw, opengl-compat

I have drawn a sphere using GLUT in a GLFW context. The code I used is:

```cpp
void drawSphere(std::vector<GLfloat> color, std::vector<GLdouble> position, float radius) {

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glColor3f(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(position[0], position[1], position[2]);
    glutSolidSphere(radius, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

and I call it in my `main()` function loop, that looks like this:

```cpp
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    // other stuff...
    drawSphere({(GLfloat)1.0, (GLfloat)1.0, (GLfloat)1.0}, {(GLdouble)2.0, (GLdouble)2.0, (GLdouble)2.0}, 1.0);
    // other stuff...
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

But, no matter what color or what position I specify, what I will get is an awesome, red sphere centered in (0, 0, 0). Altough if I modify the radius the sphere changes its dimension.

[image: Single sphere]

I've checked the code many times and almost any result on Google about how to draw a solid with GLUT, but couldn't find an answer to my problem. Also, I've tried to draw two spheres by calling the function twice, giving two different positions and two different colors. The two spheres are drawn, but they are both red and centered in (0, 0, 0), as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: Inside the bigger sphere]

Since I also draw other stuff using VAOs, VBOs and EBOs with a Vertex and a Fragment shader, could this be a problem? Could it be a compatibility issue between GLUT and GLFW? What can I do to fix this issue?

EDIT: Thanks to @Rabbid76 I've managed to solve the position problem using `glUseProgram(0)`, while `glBindVertexArray(0)` didn't seem to affect the program behaviour at all. Still, now I am facing another issue: since I draw everything using shaders, I've also got a model matrix, a view matrix and a projection matrix to deal with. When I draw the sphere using the gl pipeline, it is shown in a corner of the camera visual:

[image: Camera visual issue]

and whatever movement I make with the camera (using mouse and keyboard), the sphere will remain in that position (in the camera POV). I think this is happening because of the different way I use to draw the object, but I don't know how to set the sphere to the right position using the gl pipeline commands. What can I do? Is there some sort of useful guide or tutorial to follow to make things work?

Comment: Try `glUseProgram(0);` and `glBindVertexArray(0)` before you draw the sphere. Instead of `glutSolidSphere` you can try [`gluSphere`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluSphere.xml)

Comment: Mixing modern OpenGL with fix-function pipeline commands (aka OpenGL 1.1 API) would make me feel uncomfortable in general.

Comment: @Rabbid76 `glUseProgram(0)` did work, thank you! Anyway, now I have another issue and then I edited my question.

Comment: @Scheff Yes I know, it makes me feel uncomfortable too, but this is the only way I've found so far to draw complex shapes without having to specify every single vertex (even if with a parametric equation and so on). Also, it seems to be way lighter. I will consider refactoring after I've finished, though. Also, if you have any tip or advice regarding a good way to make the code more uniform, I will really appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] I've also got a model matrix, a view matrix and a projection matrix to deal with. [...] I don't know how to set the sphere to the right position using the gl pipeline commands. [...]

In [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL), the fixed function coordinate attribute which is specified by [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) (respectively the vertex corodinate which is set by [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml)), is transformed by the current modelview matrix (`GL_MODELVIEW`) and current projection matrix (`GL_PROJECTION`).

If you've setup a 4x projection and (model)view matrix, the this matrices can be loaded to the current matrix by [`glLoadMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml). The matrix has to be provided by a pointer to 16 consecutive values, which are used as the elements of a 4x4 column-major matrix.
The current matrix (type) can be selected by [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml).

Load the projection and (model)view matrix before you darw the geometry by `glutSolidSphere`. e.g.:

```cpp
const GLfloat *projection = ...; // pointer to 4x4 matrix (16 consecutive floats)
const GLfloat *view       = ...; // pointer to 4x4 matrix (16 consecutive floats)


// load projection matrix
glPushMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(projection);

// load view matrix
glPushMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(view);

// concatenate model matrix to view matrix
glTranslated(position[0], position[1], position[2]);

// draw sphere
glutSolidSphere(radius, 50, 50);

// restore modelview matrix (the mode is still GL_MODELVIEW)
glPopMatrix();

// restore projection matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();

// set GL_MODELVIEW matrix mode (possibly this is not necessary)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thank you very much! Now everything works.